# How HP D2700 disk enclosure is monitored for alarms via SNMP

Tags: monitoring, storage, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

We have HP D2700 disk enclosure and we would like to monitor D2700 (connected to HP Proliant DL360G8) for alarms.I have following questions regarding this.

- What are the options available for reporting D2700 hardware alarms (disk failure, power failure) via SNMP?
- We understand the D2700 to have an Ethernet interface for controller A and B and alarms are available via SNMP via this interface.
- Can anyone provide the actual alarms via this interface? (MIB and alarm list)
  As we have a number of D2700’s and would like to minimize the number of physical connections to the switch and associated IP addresses;
- Is there a mechanism to monitor the D2700 from the SCSI connected HPDL360 and raise SNMP alarms from the DL360 for hardware failures on the D2700?
  If so can anyone provide details and the actual alarms and MIB  via this mechanism?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to me like HP would be the best organization to check for MIBs for HP products, no?

Answer (score 2):

If you will be connecting your HP D2700 enclosures to a supported Smart Array controller housed in your HP ProLiant server, all monitoring of the storage enclosure will occur via the server's management agents and the PCIe RAID controller.

The ethernet ports you see on the rear of the controllers in the D2700 are not meant to be used. You won't be able to do anything with them. **Don't connect cables or plan cabling around this.**

You did not mention what operating system(s) you'd be using in these systems, but in any case, [select your OS from the list here](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=5177954&lang=en&lang=en&cc=us&cc=us&ac.admitted=1354027338298.876444892.492883150).

You'll want to install the appropriate HP Management Agents for your OS and go from there...

Comment: You mention that the storage enclosure monitoring will be done via server management agent,but how the stoage and server will communicate with each other?
These management agents are SNMP based and SNMP works on IP/UDP.So there must be IP connection between Storage and server to communicate when there is some alarm etc.
Why cant we use ethernet ports on back of D2700 controller and for what they are used for?
Also do you have list of alarms which D2700 can generate?

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: The communication occurs over the SAS links between the server and the enclosure. [It's the SES protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_Enclosure_Services). Power supply status, cooling fan, temperature sensors, and disk status are usually monitored.

Comment: Thanks.
Do we have any document from HP to have more information on how D2700 communicate with Server?This will help to show to customer that D2700 enclosure uses SES protcol to exchnage info about HW alarms.
Also do you know for what purpose ethernet port is provided on D2700?
Does it mean SNMP is not used here for D2700 alarm monitoring by HP mgmt Agent?

Comment: Also it seems HP D2700/P812 doesnt support SES protocol.

Comment: Use a Smart Array controller. Use the HP management agents. That's all you have to do.